# How to copy all its parent objects from the array of objects using the lodash or javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

Hi i have an object like this i want to copy the all its Parent objects,

```
permisions= [
 {
        "parent_id": "",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR1",
        "city":01
        "permission": "NO",
    },
    {
        "parent_id": "",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR1",
        "city":02
        "permission": "NO"
    },
    {
        "parent_id": "",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR1",
        "city":03 
        "permission": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "parent_id": "",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR1",
        "city":04
        "permission": "Yes"

    },
    {
        "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR1",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR2",
        "city":0111            
        "permission": "NO"
    },
    {
        "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR1",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR2",
        "city":0112                
        "permission": "Yes"
    },


    {
        "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR2",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR3",
        "city":0333                  
        "permission": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR2",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR3",
        "city":01111                 
        "permission": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "parent_id": "",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR4",
        "city":0444                
        "permission": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "parent_id": "",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR5",
        "city":0555              
        "permission": "Yes"
    }
]
```

If i select the **id:Distubutor3**  it has contains the **parent_id:"DISTRIBUTOR2"**  and  **DISTRIBUTOR2** contains the parent**_id:DISTRIBUTOR1** so it has to copy all the parent objects till end,can anybdy help me on this. the output should be like this,

```
result=[   {
        "parent_id": "",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR1",
        "city":01
        "permission": "NO",
    },
    {
        "parent_id": "",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR1",
        "city":02
        "permission": "NO"
    },
    {
        "parent_id": "",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR1",
        "city":03 
        "permission": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "parent_id": "",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR1",
        "city":04
        "permission": "Yes"

    },
    {
        "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR1",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR2",
        "city":0111            
        "permission": "NO"
    },
    {
        "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR1",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR2",
        "city":0112                
        "permission": "Yes"
    },

    {
        "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR2",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR3",
        "city":0333              
        "permission": "Yes"
    },
        {
        "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR2",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR3",
        "city":01111                 
        "permission": "Yes"
    }]
```

Comment: Do you want to check if that ID exist in the array or just do the assignment any way. I mean if there is no `DISTRIBUTOR1` should `DISTRIBUTOR2` get that property or not?

Comment: And if for example `DISTRIBUTOR2` doesn't exist, should `DISTRIBUTOR3` take the property `DISTRIBUTOR1`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir no if DISTRIBUTOR3 does't contain parent_id its should not copy anything,

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir DISTRIBUTOR3 contains parent_id as DISTRIBUTOR2 and DISTRIBUTOR2 contains parent_id as DISTRIBUTOR1 so it has to copy all the DISTRIBUTOR2 and  DISTRIBUTOR1 objects.

Comment: Are IDs always in the form `DISTRIBUTOR???` where `???` are numbers.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes ids all in the form of DISTRIBUTOR???

Comment: Will every element of DISTRIBUTOR2 have DISTRIBUTOR1 AS parent or will some have parent and some not ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var permissions = [{"parent_id":"","id":"DISTRIBUTOR1","city":1,"permission":"NO"},{"parent_id":"","id":"DISTRIBUTOR1","city":2,"permission":"NO"},{"parent_id":"","id":"DISTRIBUTOR1","city":3,"permission":"Yes"},{"parent_id":"","id":"DISTRIBUTOR1","city":4,"permission":"Yes"},{"parent_id":"DISTRIBUTOR1","id":"DISTRIBUTOR2","city":73,"permission":"NO"},{"parent_id":"DISTRIBUTOR1","id":"DISTRIBUTOR2","city":74,"permission":"Yes"},{"parent_id":"DISTRIBUTOR2","id":"DISTRIBUTOR3","city":219,"permission":"Yes"},{"parent_id":"DISTRIBUTOR2","id":"DISTRIBUTOR3","city":585,"permission":"Yes"},{"parent_id":"","id":"DISTRIBUTOR4","city":292,"permission":"Yes"},{"parent_id":"","id":"DISTRIBUTOR5","city":365,"permission":"Yes"}];

// get the ID number ("DISTRIBUTOR???" return "???")
function idNum(id) {
  return parseInt(id.substr(11));
}

function makeResult(perm, id){
  var num = idNum(id);
  return perm.map(function(p){
    var n = idNum(p.id);
    if(n < num && n != 1) // if the current object's ID is 1 < ID < max
      p.parent_id = p.parent_id || ("DISTRIBUTOR" + (n-1)); // fill id if it's not already set
    return p;
  });
}

var res = makeResult(permissions, "DISTRIBUTOR5"); // set all objects that have ID (1 < ID < 5)

console.log(res)
```

**Note:** If for example you call `makeResult(permissions, "DISTRIBUTOR5");` and there is no object that have `"DISTRIBUTOR2"` in the array, then the object `"DISTRIBUTOR3"` will have their `parent_id` set to `"DISTRIBUTOR2"` anyway.

Comment: No in the case of DISTRIBUTOR5  it's not contains parent_id so it ll return only its object with id:DISTRIBUTOR5

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think what you mean to say is that only those elements whose parents are present, along with the element itself, should be included in new output array.

If so, try this:

```
var filterParents = function(obj){

    var mappings = {};

    permisions.forEach(function(perm){

        if( !mappings[perm.id] )
            mappings[perm.id] = [];

        mappings[perm.id].push( perm );
    });

    var output = [];
    output.push( obj );


    while(obj.parent_id && obj.parent_id != '' )
    {
        output = output.concat( mappings[ obj.parent_id ] );
        obj = mappings[ obj.parent_id ] [ 0 ];
    }

    return output;

};
```

This is assuming that every element of a parent's id will have the same grandparent id.